# GXT 2.2 - MessageBox button constants

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, gxt

This is a question on how to detect which button was clicked in the MessageBox/Dialog.
GXT 2.1 or 2.2 only. **Please do not answer using GXT 3.**

Ideally, this is how I could do a confirm dialog.

```
final MessageBox box = MessageBox.confirm(
  "Confirm kill avatar",
  "Please remove " + getAvatar().getName(),
  new Listener<MessageBoxEvent>()
  {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(MessageBoxEvent be)
    {
      Button clicked = be.getButtonClicked();
      if (clicked == box.getDialog().getButtonById("yes"))
        deleteAvatar();
      else
       Info.display("Action cancelled");
    }
  });
```

- However. since box has not been defined, box.getDialog() would be NPE,
- and compiler preempts that by croaking "box not initialised",
- and cannot initialise because box has to be final,
- box has to be final because it is used in the anon Listener class.

Instead, I have to compare buttons using the button text. Which is not i18n friendly. Very bad practice.

```
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(MessageBoxEvent be)
    {
      Button clicked = be.getButtonClicked();
      if (clicked.getText().equals("Yes")))
        deleteAvatar();
      else
       Info.display("Action cancelled");
    }
```

In GXT 2.2, is this the recommended way? Or is there a better way to detect button being pressed, i18n-friendly?

I SHOULD compare buttons NOT the text of the buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (Dialog.CANCEL.equals(be.getButtonClicked().getItemId())) {

    //do action 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

I should simply construct my own confirm/alert/etc from Dialog and provide my own submit/cancel buttons with the appropriate listeners.

Messagebox is but a sandbox/example on how to do simple gxt dialogs.